# how to fix test cases issue with immutable.record

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writting test cases in react project using jest. But keeps getting error in data type for received object and expected object.

it shows :

```
expected: "BalloonHelp" : [Function Record]
received: "BalloonHelp" : Immutable.Record{"id": "BalloonHelp", content: ""}
```

can you please help to get this compare issue resolved.

Comment: do you mock `Immutable` package? also do you use `expect().toEqual()` or `expect().toBe()`?

Comment: i am using toEqual() but not able mock received object type. Also i try to import Immutable.

Comment: add code for your test(only that specific `it()`  + `import` list)